# WPF c# outlook sendEventHandler with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, parameter-passing, eventhandler

I´m creating a mail item and adding the sendEventHandler, what I need is to pass a list as parameter when calling the method inside the event.

My code:

private void method()
{
...
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(EmailEnviado);
...
}

private void EmailEnviado(ref bool Cancel) 
{
 ... 
}

What I need is something like this:

private void method()
{
...
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(EmailEnviado(**PARAMETER**));
...
}

private void EmailEnviado(ref bool Cancel, **PARAMETER**) 
{
 ... 
}

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parameters cannot be changed - the event handler signature is defined by the type library. What you can do however, is create a wrapper class that has all the parameters that you need as member properties. The event handler can be a method on that wrapper class.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Dmitry!